# Please either make or find a copy of Android's Calendar.apk

Tags: android, android-source

Can anybody grab Calendar.apk and CalendarProvider.apk from their phone and upload it here: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=1389

I don't know if it is possible.

The alternative would be to build from source which requires Linux or Mac http://source.android.com/source/download.html

The link to the source code repository for the Calendar app: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Calendar

Basically, I am just trying to get the Calendar on my emulator.

I would do this myself, but I do not have a Linux or Mac machine.

Of course, if anybody knew of a link to an already built copy on Google or some other website then that would work also.

Comment: Stackoverflow is for programming related questions only.  Requests for work are not appropriate.

Comment: Install [some kind of virtualization](http://www.virtualbox.org) and you, too, can have a Linux machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can anybody grab Calendar.apk and CalendarProvider.apk from their phone and upload it here: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=1389

Since those apps are sometimes modified by device manufacturers, you are requesting that others perform copyright infringement.

> The alternative would be to build from source which requires Linux or Mac

Those cannot just be built in isolation -- they have to be built as part of a firmware build, and those APKs would be tied to that firmware. It is possible that they will run on an emulator running the same version of Android as the APKs were built for, but that's a bit dicey.

I would focus your efforts on finding an existing firmware that will run on the emulator that has your desired apps. Or, test using an Android device that has those apps. Or, as one commenter mentioned, get yourself a Linux setup and build your own custom firmware.

Also, with respect to the issue you commented on, please do not use public issue trackers to post requests for people to do work for you that are unrelated to the issue. "The purpose is to see how the existing calendar app works before designing the customer's new calendar app" has absolutely nothing to do with the issue. You basically spammed 115 people with your request for free labor.